# How to enable security only for some servlets via web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

**Scenario:**

Security (access only via credentials) should be enabled for some servlets, but for others not. All via web.xml.

Comment: what do you mean by security ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is how it's done:**

First the security role + login config:

```
<security-role>
  <description>
    Main user for admin GUI
  </description>
  <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>my login</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

This servlet that should be accessed publicly:

```
<servlet>
  <description>Landing Page for Admin GUI</description>
  <display-name>StartServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>StartServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>StartServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>StartServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Restriction for all pages (only accessible via admin user):

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Private</web-resource-name>
    <description>Matches all pages</description>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Public are only those:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
    <description>Makes the landing page explicitly public (overrides Private above since more specific!)</description>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <!-- No auth-constraint = everybody has access! -->
</security-constraint>
```